# Email Sending error mail() function

Tags: php, html, sendmail

This error occurs when i try to use a sign up feature and im not sure as to why it is giving me this error. I have been to the page it is quoting and am still unsure as how i can correct the code that im using.. im on a go daddy hosting server if that help or is part of the error thanks :D

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 451 See
>   http://pobox.com/~djb/docs/smtplf.html. in D:\Hosting\12090176\html\flashrevise\signup.php on line 101

```
 $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);

$to = "$e";
    $from = "auto_responder@flashrevise.co.uk";
    $subject = 'Flash Revise Account Activation';
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Flash Revise Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:15px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.flashrevise.co.uk">
    <img src="http://localhost:8101/Tutorials/sandbox/myfiles/FlashRevise/style/images/logo_white.png" width="36" height="30" at="Flash Revise" style="boder:none; float:left;"></a>
      Flash Revise Account Activation </div><div style="padding:24px" font-size:17px;"> Hello '.$u.',<br><br> Click the link below to activate your account<br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost:8101/Tutorials/sandbox/myfiles/FlashRevise/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'"> Click here to activate your account now</a><br>
    <br> Login after successful activation using: <br>* Email Address:<b> '.$e.'</b><br>* Password: <b> '.$p.'</b></div></body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-VERSION 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bare LFs in SMTP

Use `"\r\n"` to end lines and headers as recommended in php manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks i used a slightly different code to do it my emails are now sending but they just send solid code and not the html format can you help please

Comment: 1) Add missing `:` in MIME-VERSION header. `$headers .= "MIME-VERSION: 1.0\r\n";` 2) Add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` header 3) Declare the same charset in email headers and html